# How to check if any of the Radio buttons are checked or not when clicked on submit button

Tags: jquery

```js
$('#customer_details_table').find("input").each(function(i, obj) {
        if (obj.checked == true) {
            var customer_id = obj.id;
        } else {
            alert('Need to select atlease one radio button');
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable" id="customer_details_table" aria-describedby="sample_1_info" style="display: table;">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th></th>
         <th>Customer Name</th>
         <th>Address</th>
         <th>Contact No.</th>
         <th>Email</th>
         <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody class="odd gradeX">

      <tr>
         <td><label class="radio"><input type="radio" class="bradio" id="20" name="optionsRadios1" value="option1"></label></td>
         <td width="20%">kiran</td>
         <td width="25%">XXXXXXX</td>
         <td width="20%">7654321987</td>
         <td width="20%">venkatrajkiran@yahoo.com</td>
         <td width="10%" align="center"><span class="label label-inverse">DeActive</span></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
         <td><label class="radio"><input type="radio" class="bradio" id="28" name="optionsRadios1" value="option1"></label></td>
         <td width="20%">kiran</td>
         <td width="25%">XXXXXXX</td>
         <td width="20%">9701429843</td>
         <td width="20%">s@g.com</td>
         <td width="10%" align="center"><span class="label label-inverse">DeActive</span></td>
      </tr>

   </tbody>
</table>
```

When clicked on Activate button i need to check if any of the radio buttons are checked are not ??

Even though i am selecting a radio button , its going to else condition ??

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable" id="customer_details_table" aria-describedby="sample_1_info" style="display: table;">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th></th>
         <th>Customer Name</th>
         <th>Address</th>
         <th>Contact No.</th>
         <th>Email</th>
         <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody class="odd gradeX">

      <tr>
         <td><label class="radio"><input type="radio" class="bradio" id="20" name="optionsRadios1" value="option1"></label></td>
         <td width="20%">kiran</td>
         <td width="25%">XXXXXXX</td>
         <td width="20%">7654321987</td>
         <td width="20%">venkatrajkiran@yahoo.com</td>
         <td width="10%" align="center"><span class="label label-inverse">DeActive</span></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
         <td><label class="radio"><input type="radio" class="bradio" id="28" name="optionsRadios1" value="option1"></label></td>
         <td width="20%">kiran</td>
         <td width="25%">XXXXXXX</td>
         <td width="20%">9701429843</td>
         <td width="20%">s@g.com</td>
         <td width="10%" align="center"><span class="label label-inverse">DeActive</span></td>
      </tr>

   </tbody>
</table>

       <button type="button" id="deactivebtn" class="btn blue" style="display: inline-block;">Activate</button>


$(document).on('click', '#deactivebtn', function(event) {
    $('#customer_details_table').find("input").each(function(i, obj) {
        if (obj.checked == true) {
            var customer_id = obj.id;
        } else {
            alert('Need to select atlease one radio button');
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        }
    });

});
```

Could anybody please help me how to resolve this ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get "Need to select atlease one radio button" messsage because you are checking all radio inputs, and there is always going to be one unchecked.

Improved version of your code using `find(":radio:checked")` selector:

```
$(document).on('click', '#deactivebtn', function(event) {
    var $checked = $('#customer_details_table').find(":radio:checked");
    if (!$checked.length) {
        alert('Need to select atlease one radio button');
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
    else {
        var customer_id = $checked[0].id;
        alert(customer_id)
    }
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3ppjfcLa/

Answer (score 0):

Only need to check if any of the radio button is checked:

```
$(document).on('click', '#deactivebtn', function (event) {    
     if ($('#customer_details_table input[type=radio]:checked').length) {
         var customer_id = $('#customer_details_table input[type=radio]:checked').prop('id');
         alert("Selected: " + customer_id);
     } else {
         alert('Need to select atlease one radio button');
         event.stopImmediatePropagation();
     }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rfzz3nmd/)**

Answer (score 0):

The function will get called for both the radio buttons. So even if you check one radio button, for another radio button it'll go to else condition

And it is better to use `value` attribute of radio button for storing values rathar than `id` attribute

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
$(document).on('click', '#deactivebtn', function(event) {
    if ( $('input[name=optionsRadios1]:checked', '#myForm').length>0 )  {
            var customer_id = obj.id;
        } else {
            alert('Need to select atlease one radio button');
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $radio_selected=false;
            $("#deactivebtn").bind('click',function(event){
                var radio_selected=false;
                $('#customer_details_table').find(":radio").each(function(i, obj) {
                    if (obj.checked === true) {
                        var customer_id = obj.id;
                        radio_selected=true;
                    } else {
                        if(i==2-1 && !radio_selected){
                            alert('Need to select at least one radio button');
                            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

HTML kept as the same.

Answer (score 0):

@preethi jain your code is here

```
$(document).on('click', '#deactivebtn', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var checked = $("input[name='optionsRadios1']:checked");
    alert(checked.attr('id'));
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qwL583b2/) checkout the link